# Access LAN when connected to OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, asus

I have an Asus router with Asuswrt-merlin firmware installed. I have the DHCP server on my router give out addresses in the 192.168.0/24 subnet. My OpenVPN server is configured as seen on [this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/files/vpn_981.png) image. The VPN subnet / netmask is 10.8.0.0 / 255.255.255.0. The `Push LAN to clients`, and both the `DNS` settings are set as shown in the image.
However I cannot connect to my local LAN when connected to the VPN server through `TUN`. When I switch to `TAP` I can make it work because then the VPN subnet / netmask is the same a my local LAN and the connected VPN clients get an IP address from the LAN DHCP pool, however I cannot connect my Android phone/iOS device to the VPN server because they don't support `TAP`, only `TUN`.

How can I access my local LAN through `TUN`?

Comment: are you running 380.65
output of logs in "system log"

Answer (score 2):

Try these, with these you'll need a username/password accounts setup additionally.... if that doesn't work you'll need to post more details and your logs.

Whenever you make changes, always export and use the new config.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi all you need add route with metric

```
route add -p 192.168.0.0/16 (router-local-ip) metric 1
```

*run cmd as administrator.

Answer (score -1):

This almost worked perfectly for me with the same problem!  Is network discovery enabled?  I'm using my Apple TV from a remote location (client) with a router to router tunnel.  When I try to access my home network while at home (server side), all the devices just show up.  When I try to access it remotely, I need to enter in the IP addresses for the devices.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This question is really old. You should delete this answer and ask a new detailed complete question and reference this one to ask for additional information. That will allow your question to be seen by more users rather than a few reviewers.